# Transmitting data from Python to C++

Tags: python, c++

So I have 2 processing units, one runs on Python and the other runs of C++. The first one will generate a set of data of around 3 - 5 values, either as a list of ints or a string. I want this value to be passed to C++, what is the best method? Like do I have to create a file in python then load it in C++? or there are an another way? This process would repeat every second， so I wish the transmission to be fast enough.

Comment: I'd use a TCP/UDP socket cos it's easy to port to other OSes.

Comment: Use some serialization library such as protobuf.

Comment: I think communication by files could be a good first solution. For faster results, using communication by socket is a solution, but more difficult to implement and debug.

Comment: Another option is to use a named pipe.

Comment: protobuf is great for situations with limited network throughput (high serialization costs, small result). Not what one would use if two programs are running on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using python's struct to pack your values in python which could be viewed as a 'struct' in c++, then send it from python to c++ using zeromq.